# How to compare columns from different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two dataframes

```
{'Category': {0: 'BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100', 1: 'LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100'}, 'Mean': {0: 4.859101849501094, 1: 3.349513603073975}, 'Absolute Mean': {0: 6.917727336706257, 1: 5.352618468237218}, 'Increase': {0: 13, 1: 13}, '%change(Increase)': {0: 9.059099374005655, 1: 6.693947747162456}, 'Decrease': {0: 7, 1: 7}, '%change(Decrease)': {0: -2.940893553150234, 1: -2.861578378804634}, 'unchanged': {0: 0, 1: 0}}
```

Second one:

```
{'Category': {0: 'BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100', 1: 'LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100'}, 'Mean': {0: 4.947988913441173, 1: 4.494044038470856}, 'Absolute Mean': {0: 6.972378375288884, 1: 6.366948207708872}, 'Increase': {0: 26, 1: 26}, '%change(Increase)': {0: 8.252561969120809, 1: 7.519148478124428}, 'Decrease': {0: 9, 1: 9}, '%change(Decrease)': {0: -4.04877892369542, 1: -3.745808338476033}, 'unchanged': {0: 1, 1: 1}}
```

I need to compare Absolute Means of both and whichever dataframe has lower absolute means then return that. How do I do that?

Dataframe 1:

[image]

Dataframe 2:

[image]

Edit:
Number of rows might vary in future so Im looking for a generic solution.

Comment: Where are the dataframes? Those are dictionaries.

Comment: These are the dataframes. Put them this way to make them reproducible.

Comment: Are you looking for a comparison based on the entire column of Absolute Mean or  comparison per row?

Comment: entire column @GilPinsky

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`, where the condition is to know which data frame has a smaller Average Mean.

For example, a solution could be:

1. Create the two DataFrame

```py
data1 = {'Category': {0: 'BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100', 1: 'LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100'}, 'Mean': {0: 4.859101849501094, 1: 3.349513603073975}, 'Absolute Mean': {0: 6.917727336706257, 1: 5.352618468237218}, 'Increase': {0: 13, 1: 13}, '%change(Increase)': {0: 9.059099374005655, 1: 6.693947747162456}, 'Decrease': {0: 7, 1: 7}, '%change(Decrease)': {0: -2.940893553150234, 1: -2.861578378804634}, 'unchanged': {0: 0, 1: 0}}

df1 =pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

```
                          Category      Mean  Absolute Mean  Increase  %change(Increase)  Decrease  %change(Decrease)  unchanged
0  BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100  4.859102       6.917727        13           9.059099         7          -2.940894          0
1     LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100  3.349514       5.352618        13           6.693948         7          -2.861578          0
```

```py
data2 = {'Category': {0: 'BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100', 1: 'LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100'}, 'Mean': {0: 4.947988913441173, 1: 4.494044038470856}, 'Absolute Mean': {0: 6.972378375288884, 1: 6.366948207708872}, 'Increase': {0: 26, 1: 26}, '%change(Increase)': {0: 8.252561969120809, 1: 7.519148478124428}, 'Decrease': {0: 9, 1: 9}, '%change(Decrease)': {0: -4.04877892369542, 1: -3.745808338476033}, 'unchanged': {0: 1, 1: 1}}

df2 =pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

```
                          Category      Mean  Absolute Mean  Increase  %change(Increase)  Decrease  %change(Decrease)  unchanged
0  BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100  4.947989       6.972378        26           8.252562         9          -4.048779          1
1     LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100  4.494044       6.366948        26           7.519148         9          -3.745808          1
```

2. I have create another DataFrame with the results:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame()
result['Category'] = df1['Category']
```

3. I use the np.where to know which DataFrame has the lower Average Mean:

```py
result['Data from'] = np.where(df1['Absolute Mean'] < df2['Absolute Mean'], 'df1', 'df2')
result['Min Absolute Mean'] = np.where(df1['Absolute Mean'] < df2['Absolute Mean'], df1['Absolute Mean'], df2['Absolute Mean'])
```

4. Output

```sh
                           Category   Data from    Min Absolute Mean
0   BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100   df1          6.917727
1   LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100      df1          5.352618
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Lorena Gil's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64468716/8664416) anwser:

```py
    import pandas as pd
            
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Category': {0: 'BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100', 1: 'LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100'}, 
                        'Mean': {0: 4.859101849501094, 1: 3.349513603073975}, 
                        'Absolute Mean': {0: 6.917727336706257, 1: 5.352618468237218}, 
                        'Increase': {0: 13, 1: 13}, 
                        '%change(Increase)': {0: 9.059099374005655, 1: 6.693947747162456}, 
                        'Decrease': {0: 7, 1: 7}, 
                        '%change(Decrease)': {0: -2.940893553150234, 1: -2.861578378804634}, 
                        'unchanged': {0: 0, 1: 0}})
            
            
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Category': {0: 'BASE2_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100', 1: 'LR_TREE_FILTER vs RETAIL 100'}, 
                        'Mean': {0: 4.947988913441173, 1: 4.494044038470856}, 
                        'Absolute Mean': {0: 6.972378375288884, 1: 6.366948207708872}, 
                         'Increase': {0: 26, 1: 26}, 
                         '%change(Increase)': {0: 8.252561969120809, 1: 7.519148478124428}, 
                         'Decrease': {0: 9, 1: 9}, 
                         '%change(Decrease)': {0: -4.04877892369542, 1: -3.745808338476033}, 
                         'unchanged': {0: 1, 1: 1}})
            
            
    df3 = df1.where(df1['Absolute Mean'] < df2['Absolute Mean'], df2['Absolute Mean'], axis=0)
```